# GetWork / Stratum

Tags: miner-configuration, getwork, stratum

I want to try to use my Bitcoin miner (`ANTMiner S4`) to generate `SHA256` hashes of arbitrary byte orders -- The first question is "is this possible?"

If so, the best way I can see to do it is to create a `getwork/stratum` server to dish-out the data to be hashed. Unfortunately, when reading about these protocols, the documentation isn't comprehensive.

I think , I can accomplish what I need by setting the "`target`" property of `getwork` to all high bits. I'm fuzzy on the '`data`' property.

If anybody could take a brief second to explain how I could use my `Antminer` to hash say [`0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C`], that would be amazing.

Comment: There are others ways to compute `SHA256` right ? Why do you want to use a server for that ?